# How to access parent class property from child class object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this, bind

there is a class called Vehicle

```
    function Vehicle() {
    this.amount = 1000;
    }
```

and there is a class called car which is extended from the vehicle

```
    function Car() {}

    Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
    Car.prototype.constructor = Car;
    var car = new Car();
    console.log(car.amount);
```

I want to print amount using car object.it means output should be 1000.
this is the way how I  tried to do that.but it's not working.in this case
 how should I use bind

```js
function Vehicle() {
  this.amount = 1000;
}

function Car() {}

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
Car.prototype.constructor = Car;
var car = new Car();

console.log(car.amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the binding of the properties to the object inside the `car` function: 
You need to execute `Vehicle` inside the car function and pass it's reference to the `vehicle` function using `call`. Now all the properties of the Vehicle function gets bound onto the `car` object.

Add `Vehicle.call(this);` to your `car` function and it will work.

More to read here [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

```js
function Vehicle() {
  this.amount = 1000;
}

function Car() {
   Vehicle.call(this); //calling the Vehicle function and bind the properties to this (or where the inheritance is really effectuated)
}

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
Car.prototype.constructor = Car;
var car = new Car();

console.log(car.amount);
```

Comment: what is the difference between call and bind.how can i use bind in this scenario

Comment: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a new function that wraps around the original. When executed it will pass the this keyword as specified. Call allows you to pass a different this reference then the owner of the function and executes the function afterwards.